# Nodejs REST API using MongoDB db.collection(...).findAsync method fails in Heroku, but work in local env

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, bluebird

I developed one Nodejs REST search API to return data from mongodb with bluebird promise API. This API works locally, but fails in Heroku with the error below.

BTW, I have other REST APIs work fine in Heroku. I guess this might be env/configuration related. Please shed some light on it.

```
TypeError: db.collection(...).findAsync is not a function
    at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] 
    (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at param (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
    at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at router (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
    at param (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:354:14)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] 
    (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at Function.process_params 
    (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:410:3)
    at trim_prefix (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] 
    (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at Function.process_params 
    (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at trim_prefix (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /app/node_modules/express-fileupload/lib/index.js:18:14
    at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7

code is below:


    const mongoose = require('../../../utils/mongodb');
    const Promise = require('bluebird');
    const mongoDB = require('mongodb');
    Promise.promisifyAll(mongoDB);
    const db = mongoose.connection.db;

    exports.searchChat = function (req, res) {
    const userId = req.params.userid;

    const getChatArray = function () {
    return db.collection('chats').findAsync({ participants: { 
    $elemMatch: { $eq: userId } } }).then(chatCursor => 
    chatCursor.toArrayAsync());};

    const promises = getChatArray().map(chat => 
    db.collection('messages').findAsync({ chat: { $eq: chat._id } 
    }).then(msgCursor => msgCursor.toArrayAsync()));

    Promise.all(promises).then((messages) =>{res.json(messages); }).catch(
    reason => chatlog.error(`retrieve chat error: ${reason}`));
    };
```

Comment: Why are you applying Bluebird `.promisifyAll` to the whole library? The [MongoDB driver has supported native promises](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/) for some time now. It seems you followed a very old blog post. Remove the uneeded bluebird library and use the regular driver calls instead. You get the error here because you failed to package your dependencies properly, so removing a dependency altogether and doing things properly will put you on the right track.

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks so much to save the day!

Comment: @NeilLunn just curious when you say "you failed to package your dependencies properly", how can that happen, as it works locally? Thanks for clarification.

Comment: You `package.json` would have been missing some of things you actually installed as dependencies. So on deplyment to a remote service such as heroku, the new build was not aware. Things can also possibly fail in install and get missed. So really this is about "removing unneeded dependencies" as you have now done.